# Multiplying two matrices using Strassen vs squaring identical matrices

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have an assignment question such as follows: when using the Strassen algorithm we have 7 subproblems usually, and I suppose this applies to any two $n*n$ matrices and the run time is $O(n^{log_27})$. However when I have an example of two identical $2*2$ matrices and I have to multiply them, I can just square them and it will give me 5 subproblems. i.e.:

```
| A11 A12 | multiplied by | A11 A12 | will give: | A11A11 + A12A21   A11A12 + A12A22 |
| A21 A22 |               | A21 A22 |            | A21A11 + A22A21   A21A12 + A22A22 |

                which is simply          | A11^2 + A12A21   A12(A11+A22)   |
                                         | A21(A11+A22)     A12A21 + A22^2 |

where the multiplications are in A11^2, A22^2, A21*(term), A12*(term), and A12*A21
```

Why can't I assume that the runtime will be  $O(n^{log_25})$? Is it because it only applies to $2*2$ matrices and not n*n in general? Or would I have additional subproblems asides from the 5 subproblems for multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Strassen algorithm for matrix multiplication, we define seven new matrices, $M_1, \dots, M_7$, where each $M_k$ does one multiplication.  This is why the run-time will be $O(n^{\log_2 7})$ all the time using Strassen's algorithm.

However, if we know our matrices are identical, then we can instead define the matrices $N_1,\dots, N_5$, where
$$N_1 = A_{11}^2 \\
  N_2 = A_{22}^2  \\
  N_3 = A_{21}(A_{11}+A_{22})\\
  N_4 = A_{12}(A_{11}+A_{22})\\
N_5 = A_{12}A_{21}.\\$$
Then for $AA = C$, we can set $C_{ij}$ to be additions/subtractions of the above $N_k$ matrices. Now our running time will be $O(n^{\log_2 5})$.

---

So, we cannot assume that our running time will be $O(n^{\log_2 5})$ using Strassen's **original** algorithm, because it won't be. We'd still have to do seven multiplications, even though they are not necessary, as be seen by your reasoning. With our modified and simplified Strassen algorithm for identical matrices though, we do obtain $O(n^{\log_2 5})$ time.

Also, the algorithm does not only apply to $2\times 2$ matrices. The algorithm is a divide-and-conquer algorithm. What we do is divide an $n\times n$ matrix into $4$ blocks, and recurse $n$ times until the "submatrices" are either $1\times 1$, or $2\times 2$.

Comment: I'm supposed to give a reason why $n*n$ multiplications CANNOT be $O(n^{log_25})$ though, even though it seems intuitive when following the idea of Strassen's algorithm for squaring the same matrix

Comment: @maregor Strassen's algorithm defines seven new matrices, which does one matrix multiplication each. Since we have seven matrix multiplications, each of size $n/2$, our recurrence is $T(n) = 7T(\frac{n}{2})$. Using the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), this is $\Theta(n^{\log_2 7})$.

Comment: But it is for matrices $x*y$. My question is why can't the same idea be used for $x*x$ matrices where we say that since there are 5 subproblems, we can assume $O(n^{log_25})$?

Comment: @maregor But we did use the same ideas as Strassen's original algorithm. We constructed five new matrices, which do five multiplications each of $n/2$ matrices. So our recurrence is $T(n) = 5T(\frac{n}{2})$, which gives us $\Theta(n^{\log_2 5})$ run-time.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot do it in $O(n^{\log_2 5})$  as matrix multiplication is not commutative.
That means if $A$ and $B$ are matrices, $AB\ne BA$ for many values of $A$ and $B$.

For more clarity
$$A_{11}*A_{12} + A_{12}*A_{22}\ne A_{12}*(A_{11}+A_{22})=A_{12}*A_{11} + A_{12}*A_{22}$$

Therefore, we cannot divide into 5 subproblems to improve on Strassens Algorithm.

See this for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543250/whats-wrong-with-strassens-method-to-compute-square-of-a-matrix